# Count number of lines only gives me "1". PHP

Tags: php, file, count, lines

Ok, so whatever code I'm trying i seem to only get number of lines: "1" no matter how many lines there is.

I have tried

```
file="$utsokning";
$linecount = 0;
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
while(!feof($handle)){
  $line = fgets($handle, 4096);
  $linecount = $linecount + substr_count($line, PHP_EOL);
}

fclose($handle);

echo $linecount;
```

and

```
$filen=file($utsokning);
$count=count($filen);
echo $count;
```

But it still wont work.

Does it have to do something with that my file is a php script and gets it's information from a database? And that the database is wierd in some way?

I do get a complete list tough and the count should be somewhere around 10-200 depending on what the result of my script is.

Comment: why not `$handle = fopen($utsokning, "r");` And does that solve the problem?

Comment: `echo count(file($utsokning));` should work .. are you sure your file is more than 1 line ???

Comment: See you have `file="$utsokning";` instead of `$file=$utsokning;` the *$* is missing and quotes are no useful here

Comment: fgets() reads one line at a time, so just incrementing the line count by one at every loop iteration will do.

Comment: "Does it have to do something with that my file is a php script and gets it's information from a database?" what in the world does this mean? I don't see database used here in any way?

Comment: "I do get a complete list tough and the count should be somewhere around 10-200 depending on what the result of my script is." this doesn't make sense either. you're reading a file, not connecting to a database. What are the contents of the file you're reading here?

Comment: @eis


'$utsokning = $utsokning . "%20AND%20+year:$valtar&start=0&rows=50000&sort=author_sort%20asc";'

And the script follow depending on what they want to search for.

Comment: for the second method use `print_r($filen);` to see the data being read.

Comment: @user1714124 so is `$utsokning` actually an URL, and not a file name? can you print out the full contents of `$utsockning` variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
$file="$utsokning";
$linecount = 0;
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
while($line = fgets($handle)){

  $linecount++;
}

fclose($handle);

echo $linecount;
```

try this